# In Sequelize, how can I filter items by values of their many-to-many association, and show all of their association values?

Tags: sequelize.js

In Sequelize, how can I filter items by values of their many-to-many association, and still show all of their association values and not just the filtered ones?

Consider these schemas (I use sequelize-typescript but it is almost the same). I have a polymorphic n-m association between Item and Tag. The n-m association is represented with the EntityTag model/table; this association has an additional "value" that represent the tag value.

A Tag is just a key(word), but this key(word) *MAY* have an associated value when it's linked with an entity (eg: an Item). This is exactly what Amazon Web Services does with its resources.

```
@Table
export class Item extends Model<Interaction> {
    @Column
    description: string;

    @BelongsToMany(() => Tag, {
        through: {
            model: () => EntityTag,
            scope: { entityType: 2 }, // For the polymorphic association
            unique: false
        },
        foreignKey: 'entityId'
    })
    tags: Tag[];
}

@Table
export class Tag extends Model<Tag> {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    id: string;
}

@Table
export class EntityTag extends Model<EntityTag> {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    entityId: number;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    entityType: number;

    @PrimaryKey
    @ForeignKey(() => Tag)
    @Column
    tagId: string;

    @Column
    value: string;
}
```

Now, ideally I would like to be able to do a query like "give me all the Items that are associated with the following tags with the following values: ('TagA' = 'Foo', 'TagB' = 'Bar')".

I understand it is a bit too complex so for now I'd just consider a more simple query like: "give me all the Items that are associated with the following single tag with the following specific value: ('TagA' = 'Foo')", where 'TagA' is the tagId and 'Foo' is the value.

Consider the following database

Tag

```
+------+
|  id  |
+------+
| TagA |
| TagB |
+------+
```

Item

```
+------+-------------+
|  id  | description |
+------+-------------+
| 1000 |     NULL    |
+------+-------------+
```

EntityTag

```
+------------+----------+-------+-------+
| entityType | entityId | tagId | value |
+------------+----------+-------+-------+
|      2     |   1000   |  TagA |  Foo  |
+------------+----------+-------+-------+
|      2     |   1000   |  TagB |  Bar  |
+------------+----------+-------+-------+
```

The SQL query I want Sequelize to automatically generate is something like this (written manually on my own):

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT Item.* 
    FROM Item 
    JOIN EntityTag 
    ON EntityTag.entityId = Item.id  AND EntityTag.entityType = 2 
    WHERE EntityTag.tagId = "TagA" AND EntityTag.value = "Foo")
    AS I
JOIN EntityTag 
ON EntityTag.entityType = 2 AND EntityTag.entityId = I.id;
```

The results of my query are these:

```
+------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+-------+
|  id  | description | entityType | entityId | tagId | value |
+------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+-------+
| 1000 |     NULL    |      2     |   1000   |  TagA |  Foo  |
+------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+-------+
| 1000 |     NULL    |      2     |   1000   |  TagB |  Bar  |
+------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+-------+
```

Unfortunately when I try to get the same result using Sequelize I am finding some difficulties. I tried this:

```
let items = await Item.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Tag,
        through: {
            where: {
                "tagId": "TagA",
                "value": "Foo"
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

that generates the following query:

```
    SELECT 
        `Item`.*,
        `tags`.`id` AS `tags.id`,
        `tags->EntityTag`.`entityId` AS `tags.EntityTag.entityId`,
        `tags->EntityTag`.`entityType` AS `tags.EntityTag.entityType`,
        `tags->EntityTag`.`tagId` AS `tags.EntityTag.tagId`,
        `tags->EntityTag`.`value` AS `tags.EntityTag.value`
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            `Item`.`id`,
            `Item`.`description`
        FROM
            `Item` AS `Item`
        ) AS `Item`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (`EntityTag` AS `tags->EntityTag`
        INNER JOIN `Tag` AS `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `tags->EntityTag`.`tagId`
            AND ((`tags->EntityTag`.`tagId` = 'TagA'
            AND `tags->EntityTag`.`value` = 'Foo')
            AND `tags->EntityTag`.`entityType` = 2)) ON `Item`.`id` = `tags->EntityTag`.`entityId`;
```

But what I get with this query is the Item populated with only the matching tag. It's missing all the other tags associated with the same Item.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1000,
        "description": null,
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": "TagA",
                "EntityTag": {
                    "entityId": 1000,
                    "entityType": 2,
                    "tagId": "TagA",
                    "value": "Foo"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the raw query result.

```
+------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+-------+
|  id  | description | entityType | entityId | tagId | value |
+------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+-------+
| 1000 |     NULL    |      2     |   1000   |  TagA |  Foo  |
+------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+-------+
```

As you can see, it's missing "TagB" with value "Bar". I'm quite lost with all the subqueries that Sequelize automatically generates. How can I solve this with Sequelize?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you find a solution ? I'm currently on the same trouble. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, although I'm not sure it's the best solution. I've put it in the answer to my own practically duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77654527/11847996

The answer is basically to create *two* of the associations you want (give at least one of them an alias so they don't conflict) and then to include them both in the query and only filter by one of them.