# Get All Associated Items In Sequelize When Filtering By Associated Items

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize.js and I have two tables 'media' and 'tags' where one media item can have many tags and one tag can tag many media items (`tags.belongsToMany(media)` & `media.belongsToMany(tags)`).

I tend to query media items by their tags, so

```js
media.findAll({ include: { model: 'tags', where: { tagName: 'movie' } } }
```

The problem is this (and variations such as `include: 'tags', where: { '$tags.tagName$': 'movie' }` will only include tags that match that tagName in the 'tags' field of all media items they return. This is not what I want. I want to see *all tags* on the media items returned, but *only* the media items that have the tag with the tagName 'movie' associated with them.

**Does sequelize provide any method to do this?**

Quick Demo:

```js
media.findOne({ include: { model: 'tags', where: { tagName: 'Pins' } } }
```

```json
// Returns:
  {
    mediaId: 3555,
    checksum: 'xyz',
    fileType: 'image',
    extension: 'jpg',
    title: null,
    description: null,
    downloaded: true,
    downloadType: null,
    dateDownloaded: null,
    createdAt: '2023-12-02T19:51:50.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-12-08T01:46:09.000Z',
    tags: [ 
  {
    tagId: 26,
    tagName: 'Pins',
    parentTagId: null,
    createdAt: '2023-12-06T23:32:53.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-12-08T01:30:14.000Z',
    mediaTagMapping: {
      mappingId: 16919,
      mediaId: 3555,
      tagId: 26,
      createdAt: '2023-12-06T23:32:54.000Z',
      updatedAt: '2023-12-08T02:15:02.000Z'
    }
  },

 ]
  },



// Expected:

 {
    mediaId: 3555,
    checksum: 'xyz',
    fileType: 'image',
    extension: 'jpg',
    title: null,
    description: null,
    downloaded: true,
    downloadType: null,
    dateDownloaded: null,
    createdAt: '2023-12-02T19:51:50.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-12-08T01:46:09.000Z',
    tags: [ 
  {
    tagId: 26,
    tagName: 'Pins',
    parentTagId: null,
    createdAt: '2023-12-06T23:32:53.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-12-08T01:30:14.000Z',
    mediaTagMapping: {
      mappingId: 16919,
      mediaId: 3555,
      tagId: 26,
      createdAt: '2023-12-06T23:32:54.000Z',
      updatedAt: '2023-12-08T02:15:02.000Z'
    }
  },
  {
    tagId: 27,
    tagName: 'Beauty',
    parentTagId: null,
    createdAt: '2023-12-06T22:32:53.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-12-08T01:30:15.000Z',
    mediaTagMapping: {
      mappingId: 16919,
      mediaId: 3555,
      tagId: 26,
      createdAt: '2023-12-06T22:32:54.000Z',
      updatedAt: '2023-12-08T02:15:04.000Z'
    }
  },

 ]
  },

*/
```

Note: this question was actually asked before but it was 5 years ago and got 0 responses so I'm not sure what the refresh policy is on old items. The link to the old question: [In Sequelize, how can I filter items by values of their many-to-many association, and show all of their association values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50190693/11847996)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a (the?) solution. The solution is to create a *second* association which you use only for filtering, and include both:

```js
// First association, this will return the tags as normal
sequelizeDatabase.models.media.belongsToMany(sequelizeDatabase.models.tags, {
    through: sequelizeDatabase.models.mediaTagMapping,
    uniqueKey: 'mappingId',
    foreignKey: 'mediaId',
    otherKey: 'tagId',
});

// Second association, this will return only matching tags
sequelizeDatabase.models.media.belongsToMany(sequelizeDatabase.models.tags, {
    through: sequelizeDatabase.models.mediaTagMapping,
    uniqueKey: 'mappingId',
    foreignKey: 'mediaId',
    otherKey: 'tagId',
    as: 'tagFilter'
});
```

Running it:

```js
await sequelizeDatabase.models.media.findOne({
    include: [ {
            model: sequelizeDatabase.models.tags,
        }, {
            model: sequelizeDatabase.models.tags,
            required: true,
            as: 'tagFilter',
            where: {
                tagName: 'Beauty'
            }
        }
    ]
});

// Returns

{
  mediaId: 3589,
  checksum: '20b7c7af0ecdf1f61da2d78277e02ebad747a65428bbfa43ac86cd272c7f1a2a59019c0295f4c114032fdd4b69c8242e05be2ab9a5029e7ccc8b727e7d660e3a',
  url: null,
  fileType: 'image',
  extension: 'jpg',
  title: null,
  description: null,
  downloaded: true,
  downloadType: null,
  dateDownloaded: null,
  createdAt: '2023-12-02T19:51:51.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2023-12-08T01:46:09.000Z',
  tags: [
    {
      tagId: 26,
      tagName: 'Pins',
      createdAt: '2023-12-06T23:32:53.000Z',
      updatedAt: '2023-12-08T01:30:14.000Z',
      mediaTagMapping: [Object]
    },
    {
      tagId: 32,
      tagName: 'Me',
      createdAt: '2023-12-06T23:40:45.000Z',
      updatedAt: '2023-12-08T01:30:14.000Z',
      mediaTagMapping: [Object]
    },
    {
      tagId: 33,
      tagName: 'Beauty',
      createdAt: '2023-12-06T23:40:47.000Z',
      updatedAt: '2023-12-08T01:30:14.000Z',
      mediaTagMapping: [Object]
    },
    {
      tagId: 39,
      tagName: 'pfp/previous',
      createdAt: '2023-12-06T23:42:48.000Z',
      updatedAt: '2023-12-08T01:30:14.000Z',
      mediaTagMapping: [Object]
    }
  ],
  tagFilter: [
    {
      tagId: 33,
      tagName: 'Beauty',
      createdAt: '2023-12-06T23:40:47.000Z',
      updatedAt: '2023-12-08T01:30:14.000Z',
      mediaTagMapping: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately it seems the association must be defined at startup as Sequelize doesn't seem to allow you to include multiple associations without having them predefined.

If I don't receive any better answers I'll mark this as a solution in a couple days or so.